# MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I get an error when trying to use MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate even though I have added the reference to the framework and added

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

The error I get is:
"error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate'"

I'm trying to have a single binary work for iPhone OS 2.2 and 3.0, so I set the Base SDK to 3.0 and iPhone OS deployment target to iPhone OS 2.2

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong here is that MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate is not available in any version of the OS before 3.0, so you wont be able to run that on the OS 2.2 and if you dont find  a way around using this class it wont be compatible with OS 2.2, from reading the docs it looks like this class is f or IPod access on the iphone, thats a 3.0 only feature...